# How can I cache my custom Docker image in GitHub Actions?

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions

I have many GitHub Action workflows that need to pull some docker images from the Docker Hub.

Here's an example of my action snippet:

```
      - name: Pull images
        run: |
            docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
            docker pull holism/api

      - name: Build production docker
        run: |
          docker build -t custom/image --no-cache --progress=plain
```

And the `Dockerfile` is like:

```
FROM holism/api:latest as builder
# rest of it

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
# rest of it
```

These images are more than 2 Gigabytes of data combined and they add 40 seconds to each workflow run.

GitHub has recently announced caching for workflows. But reading the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows), I can't figure out how can I cache these images.

How can I cache and reuse these docker images in my GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 0):

By default, in GitHub Actions the cache is scoped per branch.
This ensures a separate cache environment for every branch you have. So, if you're building multiple images on the same branch, each build will overwrite the cache of the previous build and you'll benefit from the last created cache.

To read more about cache I link the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/gha/).

Regarding your question, a Docker build consists of a series of ordered build instructions and each of these instructions results into an image layer. So caching the results from the `docker build` command means to cache the layers (Dockerfile instructions) you created during the build.

Caching the base image (the one in the FROM instruction) is equivalent to allow to cache the layers of the image because the base image is roughly just a layer for your custom image.

If you're using the same branch remove `--no-cache` argument from the `docker build` command.

Vice versa, if you want to cache from one branch to another, you need to add extra parameters `cache-from` and `cache-to` such as explained in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/gha/#synopsis).

Comment: I'm not talking about caching the output of `docker build`. I'm asking about caching and reusing the images that are in the `FROM` clause of the `Dockerfile`. I think either you misunderstood my question, or I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: I extended my answer to try to reply to your comment. Basically, the output of the docker build is a list of layers that compose your final image. If you can enable caching those layers it means you can cache also the base image. Hope it's more clear now.